# Useless documentation edits

Tags: discussion, edits, documentation

I created a topic with a few examples in OpenCV documentation. Recently, someone edited the examples. I have no problem with that. However the content of [the edit](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/61852) is a bit... Nothing changed, the person apparently removed something and put it back. Probably just to gain any future rep associated with these examples. The same person also did the same on another topic of the documentation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/61856). In fact, she did that on all examples that had upvotes. I consider this bad behaviour at least.

Is it possible that StackOverflow considers this an edit ? And also, how could it be accepted by a reviewer who's got almost 3k500 rep ?

Comment: Why would anyone write the "k" in "3k500" when they have to write all 4 digits out anyway?

Comment: I planned to write 3k5 then decided that 500 looked better ^^

Comment: Step 2: _"I planned to write 3k500 then decided that 3500 looked better"_. Or use 3.5k

Answer (score 5):

The edit summary says:

> Add syntax highlighting.

And the side-by-side Markdown diff proves that the editor did indeed add syntax highlighting to that line of code. So there's no bad behavior here. The non-Markdown diffs do make this unnecessarily hard to see though. It's an issue that's well documented here for Q&A diffs.

Comment: My bad, then. I didn't see that. It looked pretty useless with the inline display. However, the person really did that only on examples with upvotes...

Comment: @Sunreef "the person really did that only on examples with upvotes" Not relevant. He may have been looking at examples with upvotes (because they are presumably good examples) and decided to improve them.